# How does positioning work for drop down menus?

Tags: css, menu, css-position

I know dropdown menu's are created by wrapping `unordered lists` and `list items`.

How does positioning work for drop down menus?

```
<div class="nav block">
  <ul>
    <li style="border-left:1px solid black;"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"> Porfolio</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">Reviews</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Spellen</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">Releases</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Which one exactly should be the dropdown?

Comment: Are you using a framework of some kind? Is there a CSS setup for this or is it JavaScript. Also your secondary UL needs to be inside the LI that it belongs too.

Comment: You need to research on css drop downs

Comment: How do you intend to show the drop down 'sub-menus'? By mouse click or hover? You have to be a bit more detailed in your questioning without which users cannot answer you the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6jwgk/76/)**

**CSS**

```
li {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
     margin:0 10px;
}
li li {
    float:none;


}
    li li a {
        white-space:nowrap;

    }
li ul {
    position:absolute;
    top:1.1em;
    left:0;
    display:none;
    border:1px solid red;
}
li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Relative/absolute positioning was the solution for this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First huge problem, which can be the main one : your sublist **must** be wrapped into a `<li>` tag :

```
<div class="nav block">
    <ul>
        <li style="border-left:1px solid black;" ><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">About Us</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"> Porfolio</a></li>  
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Reviews</a>
            <ul>    
                <li><a href="#">Spellen</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Releases</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Here how do you show the drop down menu without css or javascript/jquery?

Comment: @Nisha We clearly haven't enough details here. I gave a solution for this obvious problem, but SO is still not a gimme-the-code website.

Answer (score 1):

The **UL** (submenu) should be inside the **LI** (of the menu)

```
<div class="nav block">
    <ul>
        <li style="border-left:1px solid black;" ><a href="#">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>   
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"> Porfolio</a></li>  
        </ul>
        <li>
        <a href="#">Reviews</a>
         <ul style="display:none;">    <!-- Sub menu -->
            <li><a href="#">Spellen</a></li>
         </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Releases</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```